# SQL for below requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some data as below;

```
select * into #temp from (
select getdate() Dt,20 Qt
union all
select getdate()-1 Dt,70 Qt
union all
select getdate()-1 Dt,20 Qt
union all
select getdate()-2 Dt,50 Qt
union all
select getdate()-4 Dt,40 Qt
union all
select getdate()-4 Dt,80 Qt
union all
select getdate()-6 Dt,20 Qt
) a
```

This data is for quantity of products produced on some given days in a batch at each time. At any point of time, I can ship only quantity < 100 and also based on batches . So if count exceeds 100, shipping number exceeds and output should look like below

```
 date                       QT  shipnum
2016-11-25 03:45:45.897     20  1
2016-11-27 03:45:45.897     40  1
2016-11-27 03:45:45.897     80  2
2016-11-29 03:45:45.897     50  3
2016-11-30 03:45:45.897     70  4
2016-11-30 03:45:45.897     20  4
2016-12-01 03:45:45.897     20  5
```

Can a CTE be used to achieve this. If else, how to achieve this

Comment: Do you have any way you can order this table? Is it always in date order?

Comment: Hi Rich, if you observe the output from the source data I provided, its ordered by date column. So the processing starts on date order and shipping num is assigned by count from QT

Comment: Qt with 50 should be 2 (shipnum) right?. because sum is 190 (20+40+80+50)

Comment: On what basis `shipnum` is calculated?

Comment: Hi Buddi, if one batch is shipped once, then the computation starts fresh. 20+40<100 so = 1, 20+40+80>100 so 1 only upto 40. Now starting fresh, 80<100 so 2, now 80+50>100 so 3 and so on

Comment: There are times when cursors are unavoidable - this is one.

Answer (score 3):

What version you are using?

Can you try this script:

```
SELECT *,SUM(qt)OVER(ORDER BY rn) AS [sum],SUM(qt)OVER(ORDER BY rn)/100+1 AS shipnum FROM (
     SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY dt) AS rn FROM #temp
) t
```

```
Dt                      Qt          rn                   sum         shipnum
----------------------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
2016-11-25 17:29:16.280 20          1                    20          1
2016-11-27 17:29:16.280 40          2                    60          1
2016-11-27 17:29:16.280 80          3                    140         2
2016-11-29 17:29:16.280 50          4                    190         2
2016-11-30 17:29:16.280 70          5                    260         3
2016-11-30 17:29:16.280 20          6                    280         3
2016-12-01 17:29:16.280 20          7                    300         4
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solution using a cursor - note I have made the dates unique to simplify this example

```
/*
drop table #temp
select * into #temp from (
select getdate() Dt,20 Qt, null ino
union all
select getdate()-1 Dt,70 Qt, null ino
union all
select getdate()-2 Dt,20 Qt, null ino
union all
select getdate()-3 Dt,50 Qt, null ino
union all
select getdate()-4 Dt,40 Qt, null ino
union all
select getdate()-5 Dt,80 Qt, null ino
union all
select getdate()-6 Dt,20 Qt, null ino
) a
*/


declare @100 int = 100
declare @rt int = 0
declare @ino int = 1
declare @dt datetime
declare @qt int
declare @rn int

declare sqlcursor cursor for
Select s.qt,s.dt,s.rn
from 
(select t.*, row_number() over (order by t.dt) rn
from #temp t) s

OPEN    sqlcursor 


FETCH NEXT FROM sqlcursor INTO @qt,@dt,@rn  
set @rt = @qt
update #temp set ino = @ino where @dt = #temp.dt


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       FETCH NEXT FROM sqlcursor INTO @qt,@dt,@rn  
       IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        if @rt + @qt > @100 
            begin
                set @ino = @ino + 1
                set @rt = @qt
            end  
        else set @rt = @rt + @qt
        update #temp set ino = @ino where @dt = #temp.dt
END   

CLOSE sqlcursor   
DEALLOCATE sqlcursor

select * from #temp order by dt asc
```